# re.sub to replace multiple lists with corresponding matches (Python)

Tags: python

Through Regular Expression, I wanted to annotate sentiment lexicon of given sentences with corresponding polarity tags, so I wrote the code lines as below.

```
import re
vocab = ['good/POSI','bad/NEAG','strong/POSI','dirty/NEGA', 'never/SWIT']
sent = ["It is really good", "strong man never gets his body dirty"]

for token in vocab:
    word = re.sub(r'(\\w+)\\/[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+','\\1', token)
    TA = re.sub(str(word),str(token), str(sent))
print(TA)
```

I tried to have the result like this.

```
["It is really good/POSI", "strong/POSI man never/SWIT gets his body dirty/NEGA"]
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't, and I have no idea which lines have a problem.
Is there any better way for the annotation?

Comment: As is, this will only ever work for `'never/SWIT'`, since you are starting with the unmodified `line` for every iteration of the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change the `vocab` list to a dictionary instead:

```
>>> vocab = {v[:v.find('/')]: v for v in vocab}
>>> vocab
{'dirty': 'dirty/NEGA', 'good': 'good/POSI', 'never': 'never/SWIT', 'bad': 'bad/NEAG', 'strong': 'strong/POSI'}
```

This way you could perform a replacement of `\w+` with a value in the dictionary:

```
result = []
for line in sent:
    line = re.sub(r'(\w+)', lambda w: vocab.get(w.group(), w.group()), line)
    result.append(line)
print(result)
```

This will output what you wanted:

```
['It is really good/POSI', 'strong/POSI man never/SWIT gets his body dirty/NEGA']
```